# C# Xamarian & .NET Monitoring Network Traffic Mac OSX

Tags: c#, macos

Currently, using JetBrains Rider as the IDE. I am running a basic example Xamarian application template for the Mac OSX desktop. Simply by creating a new project and editing the `Main.cs` only to test a simple idea.

The simple basic code added into `Main.cs` is:

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
               return;
    
            NetworkInterface[] interfaces 
                = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    
            foreach (NetworkInterface ni in interfaces)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("    Bytes Sent: {0}", 
                    ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesSent);
                Console.WriteLine("    Bytes Received: {0}",
                    ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived);
            }
        }
    }
```

Presently, I sometimes know network traffic monitoring on interfaces requires Sudo permissions so I even opened the IDE up with Sudo permissions and it does not output any bytes incoming or out outgoing. Always, zero traffic logged.

Any ideas on network traffic monitoring in C# Mac OSX with IP address's of destination capabilities or how to allow something basic such as this to work.

Output
`Bytes Sent 0`

Referencing:
[Documentation - Microsoft - NetworkInformation.IPv4InterfaceStats...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipv4interfacestatistics?view=xamarinmac-3.0)